# Azure Cosmos DB ChangeFeed with Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb

According to the documentation, one should be able to read the change feed from Azure CosmosDB in Node.js. Unfortunately, I have not found any code to do that. Here is my attempt, but I cannot get it running. I enter in the hasMoreResults branch twice but without any results in the response. The C# code I have written works without a problem.

```
import { CosmosClient } from './node_modules/@azure/cosmos/dist/index.js';
import https from 'https';

const db = 'MyNewDb';
const containerName = 'MyNewContainer';
const endpoint = 'https://localhost:8081';
const key = 'myKey';
const partitionKey = { kind: 'Hash', paths: ['/hello'] };

const client = new CosmosClient({
  endpoint,
  agent: new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  }),
  key,
});

const dbResponse = await client.databases.createIfNotExists({
  id: db,
});
const database = dbResponse.database;

const containerResponse = await database.containers.createIfNotExists(
  {
    id: containerName,
    partitionKey,
  },
  { offerThroughput: 400 },
);
const container = containerResponse.container;

const feedIterator = container.items.changeFeed('/hello', { startFromBeginning: true });
let count = 0;
while (feedIterator.hasMoreResults) {
  console.log('more results', count++); // I get here twice but no items in feeIteratorResponse.result

  const feedIteratorResponse = await feedIterator.fetchNext();

  console.log(feedIteratorResponse);
}
```

Here is my C# code which works and gives me all the results.

```
class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dbId = "MyNewDb";
            var containerId = "MyNewContainer";
            using var client = new CosmosClient("https://localhost:8081", "myKey");

            var container = client.GetContainer(dbId, containerId);

            var changeFeedIterator = container.GetChangeFeedIterator<dynamic>(ChangeFeedStartFrom.Beginning(), ChangeFeedMode.Incremental);

            while (changeFeedIterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                var response = await changeFeedIterator.ReadNextAsync();

                foreach (var item in response)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

`const feedIterator = container.items.changeFeed('/hello', { startFromBeginning: true });`

The API for Change Feed lets you read the Change Feed for a **particular value of partition key** or for the entire container.

The code you are using in C# is reading the change feed for the entire container, so apples to apples would be:

`const feedIterator = container.items.changeFeed({ startFromBeginning: true });`

If you wanted to read the change feed for a particular partition key, you need to use a value, not the partition key definition.

`const feedIterator = container.items.changeFeed('someValue', { startFromBeginning: true });`

Where `someValue` represents the partition key value of some documents stored in the container.

Comment: The last sample with the value works. Thx! But I would like to get the change feed for the entire container like in your apples to apples example. Unfortunately I get an error: `"Container is partitioned, but no partition key or partition key range id was specified."` Do you have an answer for that as well?

Comment: I would raise an issue then on [the SDK repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/cosmosdb), from the API perspective, it looks like it should work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/cosmos/items?view=azure-node-latest#changeFeed_T__ChangeFeedOptions_

Comment: I have opened an Issue on the repo hope they can clarify this. https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/18062

Comment: it seems like it only returns the latest record?  Is this expected?